# Tkinter widget opens two windows

Tags: python, tkinter

I am running Tkinter 3.5 on Win machine and when I run this code, I get two windows . I was expecting just one . BTW, I got the code form the web.It is working fine, except that bothers me the second(in backgorund) window .
Basically is a widget to navigate trough different windows(pages) with buttons .

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#

try:
    import Tkinter as tk  # Python2
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk  # Python3

class Wizard(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, npages, master=None):

        self.pages = []
        self.current = 0
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)

        self.attributes('-topmost', True)


        for page in range(npages):
            self.pages.append(tk.Frame(self))
        self.pages[0].pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        self.__wizard_buttons()

    def onQuit(self):
        pass 

    def __wizard_buttons(self):
        for indx, frm in enumerate(self.pages):
            btnframe = tk.Frame(frm, bd=1, bg='#3C3B37')
            btnframe.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
            nextbtn = tk.Button(btnframe, bd=0, bg='#F2F1F0', activebackground='#F58151', highlightcolor='red', cursor='hand2', text="Siguiente >>", width=10, command=self.__next_page)
            nextbtn.pack(side='right', anchor='e', padx=5, pady=5)
            if indx != 0:
                prevbtn = tk.Button(btnframe, bd=0, bg='#F2F1F0', activebackground='#F58151', highlightcolor='red', cursor='hand2', text="<< Atras", width=10, command=self.__prev_page)
                prevbtn.pack(side='right', anchor='e', padx=5, pady=5)
                if indx == len(self.pages) - 1:
                    nextbtn.configure(text="Terminar", bd=0, bg='#F2F1F0', activebackground='#F58151', highlightcolor='red', cursor='hand2', command=self.close)

    def __next_page(self):
        if self.current == len(self.pages):
            return
        self.pages[self.current].pack_forget()
        self.current += 1
        self.pages[self.current].pack(fill='both', expand=1)

    def __prev_page(self):
        if self.current == 0:
            return
        self.pages[self.current].pack_forget()
        self.current -= 1
        self.pages[self.current].pack(fill='both', expand=1)

    def add_page_body(self, body):
        body.pack(side='top', fill='both', padx=6, pady=12)

    def page(self, page_num):
        try:
            page = self.pages[page_num]
        except KeyError("Pagina Invalida! : %s" % page_num):
            return 0
        return page

    def close(self):
        if self.validate():
            self.master.iconify()
            print (' TK Wizard finished... ')
            self.destroy()
            self.master.destroy()

    def validate(self):
        return 1 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title(' TK Wizards ')
    wizard = Wizard(npages=3, master=root)
    wizard.minsize(400, 350)
    page0 = tk.Label(wizard.page(0), text='Pagina 1: ...Bienvenido al Wizard de TK !')
    page1 = tk.Label(wizard.page(1), text='Pagina 2: Acepta las condiciones de la WTFPL ?')
    page2 = tk.Label(wizard.page(2), text='Pagina 3: Felicitaciones, nada no se ha instalado correctamente.')
    wizard.add_page_body(page0)
    wizard.add_page_body(page1)
    wizard.add_page_body(page2)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 10):

The additional, blank window is the root window. Add a call to

```
root.withdraw()
```

Just underneath the `root.title(' TK Wizards ')` line, should do the trick

Comment: Happy to help. Please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer if it solved your problem to let other users know that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 5):

In the `main` area, you create a `tkinter` object, which will produce a window:

```
root = tk.Tk()
```

Then, in the `Wizard` class's `__init__`, you create a `Toplevel` object:

```
tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
```

So you're really creating the GUI in this new `Toplevel` window. You can change your program to create the app in the root window, which requires changing the `Wizard` class to inherit from the default `object` and changing the program to act on a saved `self.master` root object wherever it used to act on the `Wizard` object (which is no longer a `Toplevel` object).

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk  # Python2
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk  # Python3

class Wizard(object):
    def __init__(self, npages, master=None):

        self.pages = []
        self.current = 0
        self.master = master
        self.master.attributes('-topmost', True)


        for page in range(npages):
            self.pages.append(tk.Frame(self.master))
        self.pages[0].pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        self.__wizard_buttons()

    def onQuit(self):
        pass 

    def __wizard_buttons(self):
        for indx, frm in enumerate(self.pages):
            btnframe = tk.Frame(frm, bd=1, bg='#3C3B37')
            btnframe.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
            nextbtn = tk.Button(btnframe, bd=0, bg='#F2F1F0', activebackground='#F58151', highlightcolor='red', cursor='hand2', text="Siguiente >>", width=10, command=self.__next_page)
            nextbtn.pack(side='right', anchor='e', padx=5, pady=5)
            if indx != 0:
                prevbtn = tk.Button(btnframe, bd=0, bg='#F2F1F0', activebackground='#F58151', highlightcolor='red', cursor='hand2', text="<< Atras", width=10, command=self.__prev_page)
                prevbtn.pack(side='right', anchor='e', padx=5, pady=5)
                if indx == len(self.pages) - 1:
                    nextbtn.configure(text="Terminar", bd=0, bg='#F2F1F0', activebackground='#F58151', highlightcolor='red', cursor='hand2', command=self.close)

    def __next_page(self):
        if self.current == len(self.pages):
            return
        self.pages[self.current].pack_forget()
        self.current += 1
        self.pages[self.current].pack(fill='both', expand=1)

    def __prev_page(self):
        if self.current == 0:
            return
        self.pages[self.current].pack_forget()
        self.current -= 1
        self.pages[self.current].pack(fill='both', expand=1)

    def add_page_body(self, body):
        body.pack(side='top', fill='both', padx=6, pady=12)

    def page(self, page_num):
        try:
            page = self.pages[page_num]
        except KeyError("Pagina Invalida! : %s" % page_num):
            return 0
        return page

    def close(self):
        if self.validate():
            self.master.iconify()
            print (' TK Wizard finished... ')
            self.destroy()
            self.master.destroy()

    def validate(self):
        return 1 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title(' TK Wizards ')
    wizard = Wizard(npages=3, master=root)
    wizard.master.minsize(400, 350)
    page0 = tk.Label(wizard.page(0), text='Pagina 1: ...Bienvenido al Wizard de TK !')
    page1 = tk.Label(wizard.page(1), text='Pagina 2: Acepta las condiciones de la WTFPL ?')
    page2 = tk.Label(wizard.page(2), text='Pagina 3: Felicitaciones, nada no se ha instalado correctamente.')
    wizard.add_page_body(page0)
    wizard.add_page_body(page1)
    wizard.add_page_body(page2)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Got errorFile "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2095, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'Wizard' object has no attribute 'tk'

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce that error. The posted code works fine on my machine (Windows 7, Python 3.4.2). What line in the actual program was responsible for the error?

Comment: TigerhawkT3, I am sorry. Did not make all the suggested changes. Your code works perfect . Thank you!!!!

Comment: @Martin, if this solved the issue, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark beneath the voting buttons.